Can't create Azure Storage Account: SubscriptionNotFound
I'm working through some tutorials, and after successfully creating a resource group, I cannot create a corresponding storage account.
az login

Cmd to create resource group:
az group create --location "Central US" --name <my_resource_group_name>

This runs with "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
Cmd to create account storage:
az storage create --name "some_name" --resource-group <my_resource_group_name> 

This fails with (SubscriptionNotFound)
Subscription <my_subscription_id> was not found.
Code: SubscriptionNotFound
Message: Subscription <my_subscription_id> was not found.

Is the tutorial missing a step in between? Azure is obviously 'finding' my subscription id, but I'm not sure what else is causing the error.

Please edit your question and include the complete script. Also include the links you’re referencing.

Thanks @GauravMantri, I added as much additional context as I could.

@DavidRanzolin Check this resource provider registered in subscription or not for storage account refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465448/new-azstorageaccount-claims-subscription-not-found

@Venkatesan - Please add your comment as an answer. Thanks.

@Venkatesan thanks, I just had to register Microsoft.Storage to my subscription! I'll mark your comment as the answer if you make it one.

@DavidRanzolin Posted an answer.


Subscription <my_subscription_id> was not found.
Code: SubscriptionNotFound
Message: Subscription <my_subscription_id> was not found.

The above error occurs when Microsoft.Storage Resource Provider is not registered for the subscription.
Portal:
Portal-> < Your-Subscription> -> Resource providers -> search Microsoft. Storage -> Register.


It appears somehow the correct command from the source github.com was not used. The command should be az storage account create. You seemed to have used az storage create. obviously, you missed the account part of the Azure CLI command.
 az storage account create --name "azst112345667anthony" --resource-group "Test" 

Note the naming convention you cannot use special characters please check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview.

Storage account names must be between 3 and 24 characters in length
and may contain numbers and lowercase letters only.

Your storage account name must be unique within Azure. No two
storage accounts can have the same name.


Example: command will correctly work as below.

